# wmic filter out several lines by name or specific values

Tags: windows, command-line, command, wmic

I am currently working on a batch file to note several informations about the computer and now I've got another obstacle which I would like to remove.

As some of you might know it, some of the wmic commands output is rather big and you need to can choose which column you want to see, but for some of those commands it's still pretty much filled with a lot of informations which keep filling up the files.

I've seen there is the command `for` but I haven't really got a clue how it works exactly because I would like to sort some of the lines to be excluded from the output. Let's take the command `wmic nicconfig` for example. I only need to informations of the currently used network adapters which are normally just the LAN port and wifi, which at least recieve an IP-Address and/or have a MAC Address which I need to write down.

My question is: Is it possible to explude every line which contains specific word in the description, "Wan Miniport" or "Check Point Virtual Network" f.ex., and/or are Null or empty in MAC Addresses?

Under SQL it would be as simple as just finding the right column name but this isn't sql and therefor I'm stuggling pretty much with this perhaps simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a possible solution.

It will be something like this:

```
type C:\TestTextFile.txt | findstr /v Word1 | findstr /v /x Word2 > C:\TestTextFile2.txt
```

It will just need a little bit more work of defining the rest of the lines which should be excluded. I will try to figure it out with [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).